# How to initialize class member functions by default in C?

Tags: c++, c, class

I have implemented a data structure in C similar to the class in C++.
But I found that whenever the class contains a member function, then I have to manually point the class member function to a specific function in the code every time.
Whereas in C++ there is no need to point the member function to anyone, because C++ implements member functions directly in the class.

like this:

C:

```c
typedef struct {
    // declare func as pointer to function returning void
    void (*func)();
} ClassTest;

// Example Function
void func_1()
{
    printf("test done.\n");
}

int main()
{
    ClassTest obj;

    // You must manually point the function pointer in
    // the structure body to this function.
    obj.func = func_1;

    obj.func(); // call function
    return 0;
}
```

C++

```cpp
// Classes with the same functionality in C++
class ClassTest {
    public:
        void func() {
            printf("test done.\n");
        }
};

ClassTest obj = ClassTest();
obj.func();
```

Is there a way to make C initialize member functions by default like C++ without having to point to them manually?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but member functions in C++ are *not* stored as function pointers. That would just bloat the objects unnecessarily

Comment: You can initialize with a compound literal, I think it's called? `test_ctx obj = (test_ctx){func_1}; obj.func();` Can't think of an automagical way: https://godbolt.org/z/nzWrdME67

Comment: C doesn't have any default initialization of struct members. It has to be done explicitly when you're declaring the variable.

Comment: Usually in C you'd create a function `test_ctx_func(test_ctx*);` instead of adding function pointers. Note that you've got the equivalent of a ***`static`*** member function anyways; there's no way for the `func_1` which object it was called for. Usually you'd add an init function for doing initializations for members, e.g. `void test_ctx_init(test_ctx* ctx) { assert(ctx != NULL); ctx->func = &func_1; }`

Comment: @Barmar It's not a "default initializer", but `static` and file-scope structures are implicitly initialized to all zeros.  (I know you know that - this of for others...)

Comment: @AndrewHenle True, I meant that in the context of being able to specify a default value, as the question asks. And since he's creating objects dynamically, static variables are also irrelevant.

Comment: Congratulations on writing an exceptionally rare question that correctly and simultaneously uses both the C and C++ tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using a "template" object, initializing each instance of `test_ctx` becomes much easier.

If you ever update type `test_ctx` (perhaps by adding more functions), you only need to update the template, and all other instance of the object (`obj` and `objB` below) get updated automatically because they're all copied from the template.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
    void (*func)();
} test_ctx;

void func_1()
{
    printf("test done.\n");
}

// Create a "template" to copy from for new objects
// const makes it more difficult to accidentally change the template.
const test_ctx tmpl_test_ctx = { .func = func_1 };


int main(void)
{
    test_ctx obj = tmpl_test_ctx;  // Use the template to initialize a new object
    test_ctx objB = tmpl_test_ctx; // Every new object must be initialized from the template.
    
    obj.func();  // Now the object is ready to use
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use function?

like this:

```c
typedef struct {
    uint8_t *src, *dst;
    size_t srcSize, dstSize;
    size_t (*snB64E_size)(snSize srcSize);
    size_t (*snB64D_size)(snByte *src, snSize srcSize);
    void   (*snBase64Encode)(snByte *dst, snByte *src, snSize srcSize);
    void   (*snBase64Decode)(snByte *dst, snByte *src, snSize srcSize);
} ctx;

void malloc_init(ctx **obj)
{
    if(!(*obj)) {
        (*obj) = (ctx *)malloc(sizeof(ctx));
    }
    (*obj)->snBase64Encode = snBase64Encode;
    (*obj)->snBase64Decode = snBase64Decode;
    (*obj)->snB64E_size = snB64E_size;
    (*obj)->snB64D_size = snB64D_size;
}

int main()
{
    ctx *obj = (ctx *)malloc(sizeof(ctx));
    malloc_init(&obj);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the "template object" and "init function", you could define a macro:

```
#define INIT_CTX { .func = func1 }
```

And use it like this:

```
test_ctx obj_1 = INIT_CTX;
test_ctx obj_2 = INIT_CTX;
```